# Flutter emulator in visual studio code

Tags: flutter

[This use the phone](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qyD7r.png)
[This use the emulator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UqYGx.png)

Here I have used the emluator and the handphone is still the same
does anyone have the same problem as me?? Is there any way to fix it??
do i have to reinstall flutter

I hope there is a way to fix it